# Having issues running android studio emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I am running a java project in android Studio. I had no compilation errors.  Every time I attempt to run the android emulator, this message pops up:
[image]

How do I delete space in my emulator?

Comment: edit your AVD and add more space to it. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio:

`Open AVD Manager` > `Edit this AVD` > `Show advanced settings` > Increase your storage

Comment: Where would I open AVD Manager

Comment: In Android Studio menu go to `Tools` > `Android` > `Open AVD Manager`.